# Getting R Error: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument >

Tags: r, aggregate

I am new to R. When I wrote this code:

```
aggregate(x= IP.Causes$TOTAL.by.Type,
          by= list(IP.Causes$Payment.Type),
          FUN=sum)
```

I got an error:

Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument

How should I change that to the correct version? Thank you.

Comment: It may be better with `formula` i.e. `aggregate(TOTAL.by.Type ~ Payment.Type, IP.Causes, FUN = sum)`

Comment: I used several ways to do it, but the error is still the same.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Sounds like your data was not imported correctly. Are you sure `IP.Causes$TOTAL.by.Type` is numeric? The error sounds like it's currently a character vector. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.